# R Programming find the first entry in a list bigger than

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

Suppose that we have the table x:

```
V1   V2   V3     
1    8    18      
95   36  -40     
-67 -68  -27     
192   2   9    
160  105  36
```

I want to find the 1st row from the V1, which is bigger than 100. In our case the 192 is the 1st bigger number than 100. So i want to get 4 as an output, because 192 is the 4th row in V1.

How can I achieve this? I tried this:

```
for (i in 1:length(x$v1){
    if(x[1,i]>=100){
      print(i)
      break}    
}
```

But it didn't work. The **R** compiler says this:

```
Error in if (x[1, i] >= 100) print(i) : argument is of length zero
>         break    
Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

What can I do?

Comment: `which(x$V1 > 100)[1]`

Comment: `match(TRUE, x$V1 > 100)` should also work. `match` by definition gives index for only the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the column index of the first entry in each row with `max.col`

```
j1 = max.col(df1 > 100, 'first')
j2 = j1 * NA^!rowSums(df1 > 100)
```

Then extract the value with row/column indexing

```
na.omit(df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), j2)])[1]
#[1] 192
```

---

If we are only checking the first column, `which.max` can be used

```
which.max(df1$V1 > 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop with:

```
for (i in 1:length(df[,1])){
     if(df[i,1]>=100){
         print(i)
         break}    
}
```

Comment: for (i in 1:length(x$v1[,1])){
     if(x$V1[i,1]>=100){
         print(i)
         break}    
 } 
>Error in x$V1[i, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions